# How can I wait for child processes?

Tags: python, linux

I have a Python script that starts tasks like this:

```
import os
os.system("./a.sh")
do_c()
```

But `a.sh` is a bash script that starts other programs. The bash script itself seems to be ready before all scripts that are started are ready.

How can I wait for all scripts (child processes) to be ready, before `do_c()` gets executed?

Clarification: When I write ready, I mean finish / exit.

### Example

#### run.py

This file can be changed. But don't rely on sleep, as I don't know how long `a.py` and `b.py` take.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from time import sleep

print("Started run.py")
os.system("./a.py")
print("a is ready.")
print("Now all messages should be there.")

sleep(30)
```

#### a.py

This may not be modified:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import sys

print("  Started a.py")
pid = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "b.py"])
print("  End of a.py")
```

#### b.py

This may not be modified:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from time import sleep

print("    Started b.py")
sleep(10)
print("    Ended b.py")
```

#### Desired output

The last message has to be `Now all messages should be there.`.

#### Current output

```
started run.py
  Started a.py
  End of a.py
a is ready.
Now all messages should be there.
    Started b.py
    Ended b.py
```

Comment: How does `script.sh` start other processes? Do any of those processes daemonize themselves?

Comment: By "ready" you mean "exit", right? If `script.sh` exits before the programs it starts exit, it will not be easy to wait for them. Can you modify `script.sh` so it waits for its child processes?

Comment: @user4815162342: Yes, I mean "exit". No, I can't modify `script.sh`. I've added an example.

Comment: @univerio: I don't know what it means when processes daemonize themselves. But I've added an example of a similar situation above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual approaches for handling this kind of situations don't work. Waiting for `a.py` (which `os.system` does by default) doesn't work because `a.py` exits before its children are done executing. Finding the PID of `b.py` is tricky because, once `a.py` exits, `b.py` can no longer be connected to it in any way - even the parent PID of `b.py` is 1, the `init` process.

However, it is possible to make use of inherited file descriptor as a poor man's signal that a child is dead. Set up a pipe whose read end is in `run.py`, and whose write end is inherited by `a.py` and all its children. Only when the last child exits will the write-end of the pipe be closed, and a `read()` on the read-end of the pipe will cease to block.

Here is a modified version of `run.py` that implements this idea, displaying the desired output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from time import sleep

print("Started run.py")

r, w = os.pipe()
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    os.close(r)
    os.execlp("./a.py", "./a.py")
    os._exit(127)   # unreached unless execlp fails
os.close(w)
os.waitpid(pid, 0)  # wait for a.py to finish
print("a is ready.")

os.read(r, 1)       # wait for all the children that inherited `w` to finish
os.close(r)
print("Now all messages should be there.")
```

---

**Explanation:**

Pipe is an inter-process communication device that allows parent and child processes to communicate through inherited file descriptors. Normally one creates a pipe, fork a process, possibly executes an external file, and reads some data from the read-end of the pipe, the same data written by another to the write-end of the pipe. (Shells implement pipelines using this mechanism by going one step further and making the standard file descriptors such as stdin and stdout point to the appropriate ends of a pipe.)

In this case, we don't care about exchanging actual data with the children, we only want to be notified when they exit. To achieve that, we make use of the fact that when a process dies, the kernel closes all of its file descriptors. In turn, when a forked process inherits file descriptors, the file descriptor is considered closed when all the copies of the descriptor are closed. So we set up a pipe with a write-end that will get inherited by all the processes spawned by `a.py`. These processes don't need to know anything about this file descriptor, the only important thing is that when they all die, the write-end of the pipe will close. This will indicate at the read-end of the pipe by `os.read()` no longer blocking and returning a 0-length string that signals the end-of-file condition.

The code is a simple implementation of that idea:

- The part between `os.pipe()` and the first `print` is an implementation of `os.system()`, with the difference that it closes the read-end of the pipe in the child. (This is necessary — simply calling `os.system()` would keep the read-end open which would prevent the final read in the parent from working correctly.)
- `os.fork()` duplicates the current process, with the only way to differentiate the parent and the child being that in the **parent** you get the child PID (and the child gets 0, since it can always find out its PID using `os.getpid()`).
- The `if pid == 0:` branch runs in the child, and only execs `./a.py`. "Exec" means that it runs the specified executable *without ever returning*. The `os._exit()` is only there in case `execlp` fails (probably unnecessary in Python because failure of `execlp` would raise an exception which would exit the program, but still). The rest of the program runs in the parent.
- The parent closes the write-end of the pipe (otherwise attempting to read from the read-end would deadlock). `os.waitpid(pid)` is the waiting for `a.py` normally performed by `os.system()`. In our case it's not necessary to call `waitpid`, but it's a good idea to do so to prevent a zombie from remaining.
- `os.read(r, 1)` is where the magic happens: it attempts to read at most 1 character from the read end of the pipe. Since no one ever writes to the write-end of the pipe, reading will block until the write-end of the pipe is closed. Since the children of `a.py` know nothing of the inherited file descriptor, the only way for it to be closed is by the kernel doing it after the death of the respective processes. When all of the inherited write-end descriptors are closed, `os.read()` returns a zero-length string, which we ignore and proceed with the execution.
- Finally, we close the write-end of the pipe, so that the shared resource is freed.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks for the long answer! Although it works fine with the example setup I've provided, this does not work at work. I think the problem is SLURM. Some jobs (which I have to wait for) submit jobs to SLURM that have to finish before I can continue. But I think that will be another question / some more clarification on my side.

Comment: Can you possibly elaborate on closing the write-end in parent, and the read-end in child? Why exactly do we need those?

Comment: @x-yuri Closing the write-end in the parent is necessary because we want the write-end inherited by the child to be the only extant file descriptor that refers to the write-end of the pipe. That way the grandchild exiting causes the pipe to close and `os.read(r)` to read the 0-length EOF marker. If we didn't close `w` in the parent, the parent would still hold on to the write-end of the pipe, and the final `os.read(r)` would just hang indefinitely, waiting for data that will never arrive. Closing the read-end in the child might not be necessary, but is a good idea as the child doesn't need it.